# Left to right for DateTimePicker in C#

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I have a `DateTimePicker` with this properties:

```
    this.CustomFormat = "HH:mm";
    this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;                
    this.ShowUpDown = true;
    this.Text = "08:45";
```

everything ok, but when i changed format to persian in control panel:

[image]

my time change to "45:08"

I want to be this way: "08:45"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [DateTimePicker.RightToLeftLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.righttoleftlayout(v=vs.110).aspx) Property

> Gets or sets whether the contents of the DateTimePicker are laid out
>   from right to left.

Something like this:

```
if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft)
{
   this.dateTimePicker.RightToLeftLayout = true;
}
else
{
   this.dateTimePicker.RightToLeftLayout = false;
}
```

Also check **[What is RightToLeftLayout?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsarabic/archive/2010/02/18/what-is-righttoleftlayout.aspx)**

Comment: @javadaskari:- Did you tried to use the [PersianCalendarClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/%20system.globalization.persiancalendar.aspx)?

Comment: ________ yes _________